# Unity Vector3.MoveTowards over the span of a minute with Time.deltaTime

Tags: unity, movement

I'm trying to figure out how to use `Time.deltaTime` to let me move an object over the course of a minute.

From my understanding, `Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.localPosition, finish, Time.deltaTime)` will result in `transform` moving to `finish` over the span of one second. The same function but with `Time.deltaTime * 2` would result in the object completing the movement in the span of 30 seconds.

Therefore, I thought that `Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.localPosition, finish, Time.deltaTime / 60)` would cause the movement to happen over the course of 60 seconds. However, the move is extremely slow, and it looks like it would take several minutes to reach its destination.

I'm clearly using a wrong value somewhere, but what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better off using Lerp.

```
float ElapsedTime;
float FinishTime;
Vector3 StartPosition
Vector3 Target;

void Start ()
{
    Vector3 StartPosition = Vector3.zero;
    Target = Vector3.one * 50;
    ElapsedTime = 0;
    FinishTime = 60f;
}

void Update ()
{
    ElapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (StartPosition, Target, ElapsedTime / FinishTime);
}
```

This interpolates transform.position from the StartPosition to Target in FinishTime, which is a minute.

If you really want to use MoveTowards, you need to calculate the speed at which you need to move at to reach Target in 1 minute.

```
float Speed = Vector3.Distance (Target, StartPosition) / 60f;

void Update ()
{
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, Target, Speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

By the way, in case it's unclear: Time.deltaTime is the time between frames in seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding of Vector3.MoveTowards() is close, but not quite right.

```
public static Vector3 MoveTowards(Vector3 current, Vector3 target, float maxDistanceDelta);
```

Each time you call this method it returns a point along the vector from current to target that is at most maxDistanceDelta away from current.  So if current is (0.0, 0.0, 0.0) and target is (1.0, 0.0, 0.0) and maxDistanceDelta is 0.1 then MoveTowards() will return (0.1, 0.0, 0.0).

In general, under the hood it's doing something like this:

```
current + (target - current).normalized * maxDistanceDelta
```

The exception is that if the distance between current and target is less than maxDistanceDelta then MoveTowards will just return target.  That is, it won't overshoot.

If you want to control the speed of the movement then you just need to set maxDistanceDelta equal to the speed you want and multiply it by the Time.deltaTime, like so

```
Vector3.MoveTowards(current, target, speed * Time.deltaTime)
```

So if your speed is set to 10.0 you mean that you want the point to move 10 units per second.  Since Time.deltaTime tells you how much time passed in the last frame multiplying it by the speed tells you the maximum distance the point should have moved in the last frame.  Make sense?  Multiplying or dividing by other numbers in maxDeltaTime just ends up effectively changing the speed.  That's why Time.deltaTime / 60.0f made things so much slower.  Your implicit speed was 1 and then you divided that by 60.0f...

Finally, if you want to traverse a set distance in a given period of time then you need to figure out the total distance (outside of Update) and divide that by the total time you want to take to get a speed.  Then use that speed, scaled by deltaTime, in your call to MoveTowards() inside of Update().

See the [Vector3.MoveTowards() documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html) for more info and an example.